# How to add padding to nav-items when collapsible navbar is expanded Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Below I have code that generates a collapsible Bootstrap 5 navbar that has the buttons on the right instead of on the left however you will notice that when expanding the navbar that the nav items don't have nice padding/margins how do I write CSS rules for nav items when they are expanded only?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Document</a>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <form name="logout" class="logout ms-auto" action="PHP/Logout.php" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
          </form>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in BS5 padding and margin classes. Try below code. Let me know if you succeed.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-5 mb-2 p-3" href="index.php">Document</a>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ml-5 p-3">
          <form name="logout" class="logout ms-auto" action="PHP/Logout.php" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
          </form>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to style the element like this

```
#id-of-your-element{
  padding:50px !important;
}
```

The !important tag will override the default padding set by Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You only want the padding on mobile (less than `sm`) so use `py-sm-0 py-3` for vertical padding on the form..

```
<form name="logout" class="logout ms-auto py-sm-0 py-3" action="/echo" method="get">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
</form>
```

[Here's the demo](https://codeply.com/p/EC6OEhNbY7)